# DB query not populating to combo box...why?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I've been at this for awhile and have tried different examples (including a few that I found here), and tried to adapt them to what I need.

I am trying to use a DB query in a servlet to populate a combo box in the resulting html form that is created.  While it all compiles and the page pops up with a combobox, there is nothing in the box to choose from, which tells me that something is wrong with how I am passing variables.

I've basically narrowed my methods down to two, but get the same results from both.
Can someone have a look-see and give me a clue?

```
out.print(`"<tr><td>SoldWhich Home ID:  `</td><td>"`);
//Query table for results to go into option box  
ResultSet rs1 = null;  
Statement stmt1 = null;  
Connection con1 = null;  

try {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);  
    con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);  
    String sql = "SELECT home_id FROM Home";  
    stmt1 = con1.createStatement();  
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);  
    ArrayList<String> soldWhich = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> soldWhich = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs1.next()){
        for (int i=1;i<=rs1.getRow(); i++ ){
            String value = rs1.getString(1);
            soldWhich.add(value);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e){}
//Begin option box
out.print(`"<select width=\"150px\" align=\"right\" name=\"soldWhichBox\">"`);
String soldWhich[] = (String[])req.getAttribute("home_id");
//populate with query output
try{
    for(String sh : soldWhich){
        out.print(`"<option width=\"150px\" align=\"right\" value=\""+sh+"\">"+sh+"</option>"`);
    }
    rs1.close();
    con1.close();
}

catch (Exception e){}
out.print(`"</select>"`);
out.print(`"</td></tr>"`);
```

And the other method:

```
out.print(`"<tr><td>SoldWhich Home ID:  </td><td>"`);
//Query table for results to go into option box  
ResultSet rs1 = null;  
Statement stmt1 = null;  
Connection con1 = null;  
try{  

    Class.forName(DRIVER);  
    con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
    String sql = "SELECT home_id FROM Home ORDER BY home_id";
    stmt1 = con1.createStatement();
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);
    List<String> soldWhich = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs1.next()){
       soldWhich.add(rs1.getString(1));
    }
}
catch(Exception e){}
//Begin option box
out.print(`"<select width=\"150px\" align=\"right\" name=\"soldWhichBox\">"`);
String soldWhich[] = (String [])req.getAttribute("home_id");
//populate with query output
try{
    for(String sh : soldWhich){
        out.print(`"<option width=\"150px\" align=\"right\" value=\""+sh+"\">"+sh+"</option>"`);
    }
    rs1.close();
    con1.close();
}
catch (Exception e){}
out.print(`"</select>"`);
out.print(`"</td></tr>"`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you setting "home_id" request attribute and why are you even setting it? I think you should take out the following line of code and see if it works. Modify your code to this.

```
List<String> soldWhich = null;
try {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);  
    con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);  
    String sql = "SELECT home_id FROM Home";  
    stmt1 = con1.createStatement();  
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);  
    soldWhich = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs1.next()){
        for (int i=1;i<=rs1.getRow(); i++ ){
            String value = rs1.getString(1);
            soldWhich.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, If I remove that line, the variable "soldWhich" in the for-each loop becomes uninitilaized...sigh...this stuff gets more and more complicated by the minute...

Comment: Define List<String> soldWhich before the try block and take  List<String> out inside the try block.

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/users/gcurrier/folders/Jing/media/a208d64f-e376-4470-809f-651c0e51bc5e

Comment: Cool. I would like to request you to accept an answer if it has resolved your problem and an up vote is appreciated.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, that little part has just unlocked the rest ofmy application.  Now I have a chance at finishing it!  Thank you so very much! (just have to make sure i can insert with selected data - and I should be able to, and I'm good)

Comment: not a problem, let me find the way to do it and I will (i'm still new here)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not actually getting values (sh) in the "for(String sh : soldWhich)" loop. Can you try printing the values in a simple table just to see if you actually get data? Also why aren't you using jstl to perform this task? And your catch block does not log any errors either in case you are actually getting some sort of errors that will go unnoticed.

Comment: True, I am not getting values.  When I leave the second catch block out , I get a null pointer exception on the for-eacc loop line.

Comment: Additionally, I am unfamiliar with using JSP and not very sure how to go about changing everything to fit (from html to jsp to servlet).  I am basically (as you can probably tell) going from an html page to the servlet.  Without the select and option blocks I can display data for any query (providing the sql is correct) but trying to get a resultset into the the combobox is, at the moment, defeating me.  I could really use some help...